# Is there a difference between dumpdata and simply piping the output to a file?

Tags: python, django

In the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/django-admin/#dumpdata), you can see that by using `manage.py dumpdata -o file.json`, it will dump your database to `file.json`. However, without a `-o` flag specified, it simply outputs the dump to standard out. Because of this, I can also do `manage.py dumpdata >> file.json`, and the file sizes are the same size.

I understand that using the `-o` flag will show a progress bar, as written in the docs, however, are there any other differences (for example, speed)?

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be any difference between `manage.py dumpdata > file.json` and `./manage.py dumpdata -o file.json`, apart from the progress bar.

If you do `manage.py dumpdata >> file.json` then that will *append* the output to `file.json`.